# LogFormat apache 2.4 not work

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm trying to configure `mod_remoteip` in apache2.4 with proxy squid in a separate server but the IP in the access.log remains the IP of the proxy.
I use this https://trick77.com/apache2-2-4-logging-remote-ip-address-using-mod_remoteip/

In fact, I have found that in the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, the command

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

don't change the format of the `access.log` even I change the text or remove it.

Someone can help ?

Answer (score 7):

I found that using the nickname `combined` doesn't work since it is already taken. So this works:

`LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" %D"`**`myawesomeformat`**

`CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log`**`myawesomeformat`**

Comment: Took me an hour to find out. Bloody apache doesn't even issue a warning. Pulling my hair...

Answer (score 1):

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

[`LogFormat`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) creates only "nickname" for log format. Actually used format is defined by

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

[`CustomLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) which defines where and in which format the log is stored.

Comment: Not clear. I see the access.log but why doesn't it take the change i made in LogFormat, for example if i change the order of 2 parameters ?

Comment: There are more `LogFormat` lines in the config. And there might be more `CustomLog` entries. Search for them in your config. You need to pair them together AND of course restart your apache2 service, if you didn't do so.

Comment: thanks. I see 5 LogFormat and no CustomLog in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf . I see CustomLog here "apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf" but nothing in any vhost conf here "apache2/sites-available/"

Comment: Did it solve your problem already? It is not obvious from your last comment.

Comment: I have an access.log for each vhost but any change i do in the LogFormat doesn't change the format of this access.log because maybe there is no CustomLog associated with this and it takes the defaut one ?? Where should I put this CustomLog ?

Comment: of course, i restarted apache after each change